# Rails authlogic/user can't check for errors.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, authlogic

I'm trying to reference a value of the current user in rails. The current user is logged in through authlogic, but errors doesn't exist. Am I doing something wrong? I just want to be safe and tell them why they couldn't enter an address.

```
<%= form_for(current_user.address.build) do |f| %>
  <% if current_user.address.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(current_user.address.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% current_user.address.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

error:

```
undefined method `errors' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f9584665e88>
```

Answer (score 0):

delete `.any?` and try it again, good luck
also you can use `.present?` method or `.blank?`

Comment: I don't think it's making it that far. The method `errors' isn't defined so I can't interact with it's return can I? Thanks for your response!